# Outlook specific data scraping, extracting to email template & automatically sending to relevant party! Is this even possible?

Tags: email, web, automation, outlook, screen-scraping

Please help!

I work for a telecoms company, everyday I receive stacks of emails from our ISP notifying me a customer is about to exceed there broadband data allowance. I am then required to contact each customer manually and inform them of the situation and advise a recommended solution.

The **problem** is this is they are coming in quicker than I can contact customers.

What I would like to do is automate this process (The email from the ISP can not be forwarded as it contains confidential information).

The system would need to extract/scrape the following data:

- Telephone number, current data usage, data reset date.

This extracted data would need to be extracted into an email template.

It gets trickier - Now the system would need to establish which customer to send this email too!

The only way to identify a customer from the information contained in the email is the telephone number. I guess I would need to create a directory with each telephone number and associated customer email address.

Is this impossible to achieve? How would you guys go about achieving something like this? Any advice would be massively appreciated - In fact you would be a life saver.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Er, Hire a programmer to build something for you. It might put you of a job though if it were automated :-)

Comment: Ha ha very true, luckily my role is not solely this so I should still have plenty to do! Is this not something I can configure with a software program rather than programming from the ground up!

Comment: There are some autorule tools available for outlook. Not used any myself though so you'll have to look around. Personally I think the 'It Gets Trickier' bit might put the nail in the coffin for these tools. I would write a simple app in java or something that read the mailbox folder and scanned it for these messages and get the app to do all the work for your specific needs.

Comment: hi @user3004408 was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 0):

we do something similar in an add-on to Microsoft Outlook we've made to manage projects and service calls (Invantive Vision). How it technically works is as follows:

- the HTML variant of the email is sent to a webservice from within the Outlook add-in;
- the webservice sends it to a stored procedure in the database;
- the stored procedure searches and looks especially at the email address (since it seems more unique, many companies have a central telephone number with maybe 1.000 people behind it);
- the stored procedure queries the customers and persons database;
- it chooses a template in HTML with tags;
- the tags are filled based upon the data found;
- the results are given back for human validation.

Please note that the results do not have to be 100%; it will never be possible since people share telephone numbers and email addresses and might make typos. But 99% is reasonable and during the human validation phase the employee can correct and choose a different customer when necessary.

Sometimes 100% hits are possible in other scenarios. In that case we just archive the email on a project and let the system do everything automatically in the database.

Anyway, the crux is to bring the email to the data and let some type of stored procedure do the hard work and maybe sending and/or composing mail.